# How to redefine path in javascript after page load

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

actually I have a website in HTML and in the head tag I've called a js file. The website has two pages, so the real thing is in the first page the path defined in the javascript works just fine but in the second file, it doesn't...

The first file in the root of the folder and the second is in a subfolder called HTML, the js file lies in the JS folder in the main folder.

Here is the code from JS

```
function change() {
  document.getElementById("myDIV").className += (' toast-header-scrolled');
  document.getElementById("img").src = ("../Utilities/logo5.png");
  document.getElementById("name").style.visibility = "visible";
}

function back() {
  document.getElementById("myDIV").className = ('toast-header');
  document.getElementById("img").src = ("../Utilities/logo.png");
  document.getElementById("name").style.visibility = "hidden";
}
```

And the code of the HTML head tag

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="JS/addjs.js"></script>
```

From the second file

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../JS/addjs.js"></script>
```

Comment: You can take a look at the Network panel in the Browser developer tools. There you should see the urls it tries to load, and see what is (un)expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the path is relative to the document you load the JS code in.

```
"../Utilities/logo5.png"
```

won't use the correct path in the second file in the subfolder as there is no "Utilities" folder in the folder where your first html file is located. In order to work it needs to be "../../Utilities/logo5.png".

Here are two quick solutions:

1. use the absolute path like
   "http://yourdomain.com/.../Utilities/logo5.png" to link to the img
   file inside the js code.
2. use a variable when you call the function and change the js code so it generates the correct relative path.

edit, for better understanding of 2:

```
function change(prePath) {
  document.getElementById("myDIV").className += (' toast-header-scrolled');
  document.getElementById("img").src = prePath + "../Utilities/logo5.png";
  document.getElementById("name").style.visibility = "visible";
}
```

and call the function with this in the second file in the subfolder:

```
change("../")
```

use

```
change("")
```

in the first file.

This is a quick and dirty solution, there are other ways to get this done for sure. If you want to go with this in even more files located in additional subfolders, you can use the number of subfolders as variable and run a loop that adds as many "../" as needed.